# goToAndaPlay return value .. T-T on AIR for Android [Accelerometer use]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, accelerometer

[Im Newbi on as3 and adobe flash]

i want to implement accelerometer in AIR 4 Android to animate object,
here is the description of my file:
-I have 2 frames animation,
-1st frame for the menu
-2nd frame is place to animate object using accelerometer,

-When i used gotoAndPlay to go back to first frame from second frame, i feel that such kind of value also go along back to first frame,

-then when i go again to the second frame, the second frame value seems strange, like doubling value speed of object movement,

T-T
i have no idea how to solve it
Need Help from anyone,
thank you master. :D

here is the download link of flas file [Akselerometer_objek_test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfxg3dkl1sftc1j/stack%20over%20flow.fla)

Comment: a bit of code here actually would help, however maybe you should start with resetting values on frame 1. Another thing is why to use timeline? and I assume code on the frames instead of OOP approach with classes?

Comment: thanks for the reply mr Lukasz,

im not using OOP yet, bcause idnt know yet.
and how to reset value on frame one ? T-T i dnt get it.

Comment: the best way to use it is "to start". for years I haven't been coding on timeline so don;t exactly know how it behaves with AS3:) but I assume that you could define some initial values e.g. `var myVar:int = 0;` you need to show some code anyway.

Comment: Just had a quick look at the source! I couldnt realy make heads or tales of it. Neither instace names or comments are in english.
working over multible frames is generally a bad practise for exactly those problems youre haveing. But the second frame is definitely **not** passing anything to the first frame. Rather some value is added everytime you enter the 2nd frame. work with sprites as containers and use only one frame. Obviously using classes would be even better

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at the templates, it seems you have to call `removeEventListener` before `gotoAndPlay();`

Before calling `gotoAndPlay`, try doing these:

```
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);

ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
```

Replace ball with your MovieClip, then again put `removeEventListener` for each event you added.